# How to get Android sensor sampling frequency?

Tags: android, sensors

For android device, I only know that we can define the parameters for SensorManager in order to adjust the sample rate of the sensor. However is there a way to measure the sensor sampling rate accurately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPS works at 1 Hz and you cannot change that. If you ask about the internal sampling rate, you have to check what GPS chip is in your device and look at its specs.

The other sensors you can measure by taking timestamps. But i have seen devices range from 10 ms per acceleration call to 30 and more (on the fastest rate).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below:

```
private float calculateSensorFrequency() {
    if (startTime == 0) {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
    long timestamp = System.nanoTime();
    return (count++ / ((timestamp - startTime) / 1000000000.0f));
}
```

Then, call the *calculateSensorFrequency* method like below, for example, in the case of the Accelerometer sensor.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    int sensorType = sensorEvent.sensor.getType();
    switch (sensorType) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
        System.out.println("Frequency: " + calculateSensorFrequency());
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + sensorType);
    }
}
```

The calculated frequency obviously depends on the sensor delay set by you.